Hash function $h:\{0,1\}^*\to \{0,1\}^n$ with a commutativity property
Let $\{0,1\}^*$ denote the collection of finite binary strings. We consider the concatenation $|$ of elements of $\{0,1\}^*$ as a function $|:(\{0,1\}^* \times \{0,1\}^*) \to \{0,1\}^*$.
Is there a (reasonably good) hash function $h:\{0,1\}^*\to \{0,1\}^n$ with the following property?

For all $a, b \in \{0,1\}^*$ we have $h\big(h(a)|b\big) = h\big(h(b)|a\big)$.

EDIT. As Daniel's answer implies, such a $h$ would allow for the construction of pre-images. But I still wonder whether there is a reasonably exciting hash function meeting the above requirement.

What do you mean by reasonably exciting? Also, is the application not cryptography or security in general?

No. This would not be collision resistant. Pick any distinct $a$ and $b$ and $m=h(a)|b$, $m'=h(b)|a$. Trivially $h(m)=h(m')$.

Is it implied that $m\neq m'$? Oh wait nvm, it is obvious that they are!
